# Questions about the Param and Call instructions of three-address code

Tags: compilers

Section 6.2.1 of the book "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" describes three-address code. Specifically,

Procedure calls and returns are implemented using the following instructions: **$\text{param } x$** for parameters; **call $p, n$** and **$y = \text{call } p, n$** for procedure and function calls, respectively; and $\text{return } y$, where $y$, representing a returned value, is optional. Their typical use is as the sequence of three-address instructions

$$
\text{param } x_{1} \\
\text{param } x_{2} \\
\ldots \\
\text{param } x_{n} \\
\text{call } p, n
$$
generated as part of a call of the procedure $p(x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n})$.

However, I am confused about the following explanation:

*The integer $n$, indicating the number of actual parameters in "$\text{call } p, n$", is not redundant because calls can be nested. That is, some of the first $\text{param}$ statements could be parameters of a call that comes after $p$ returns its value; that value becomes another parameter of the later call.*

Could you please show me an example where the integer $n$ is necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this sequence of instructions:

```
param u
param v
param w
call f
call g
```

Should the above code be interpreted as calling `g(u,f(v,w))`, or as calling `g(u,v,f(w))`?  Without the `n`, there's no way to tell: both compile to the same assembly code.

A way you could discover this would be to try to implement an interpreter for this language, and notice that without the `n` there is no way to implement the `call` because it is not clear how far up the stack to look for parameters.